# SQLAlchemy model's __eq__ is called with symbol instance (as other) upon commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using a Declarative Base model in SQLAlchemy, and I have the following problem upon commit:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 693, in commit
  self.transaction.commit()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 332, in commit
  self._prepare_impl()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 311, in _prepare_impl
  self.session.flush()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1788, in flush
  self._flush(objects)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1870, in _flush
  flush_context.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 351, in execute
  postsort_actions = self._generate_actions()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 325, in _generate_actions
  for rec in cycles
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 325, in <genexpr>
  for rec in cycles
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 542, in per_state_flush_actions
  dep.per_state_flush_actions(uow, states_for_prop, False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/dependency.py", line 162, in per_state_flush_actions
  state, state.dict)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 699, in get_all_pending
  if original not in (NEVER_SET, PASSIVE_NO_RESULT, None) and \
File ".../workspace/file.py", line 250, in __eq__
  return self.foo == other.foo

AttributeError: 'symbol' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

When foo is an attribute of my model which is a non-SQLAlchemy class.
The reason for this is that the 'in' operator in python relies on `__eq__` to check list membership.

**The question is how to avoid changing the `__eq__` implementation to fit SQLAlchemy's quirks?**

I can obviously address the scenario in which `other` is some sort of `util.symbol` (specifically `NEVER_SET`), but I think is patchy.

### Update

This is my `__eq__` method:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.foo == other.foo
```

SQLAlchemy symbols simply have no `foo` attribute...

Comment: Shouldn't that be simply treating the AttributeError exception and returning False? After all, if other don't have the attribute, it's not equal. :p

Comment: What is your current implementation of `__eq__` look like? It seems to me that this isn't a SQLAlchemy issue as much as an `__eq__` implementation issue, and a SQLAlchemy model just happens to be an object that you're having issues with right now.

Comment: I think this goes away if you write your `__eq__` to handle arguments of arbitrary types, which is probably a good general practice.